# Issues with Access parsing double quotes in a CSV file

Tags: ms-access, csv, ms-access-2010

I have a large CSV file that I am trying to import into Microsoft Access but I am running into issues. Assume pipes represent different cells in the database

Assume my content is the below. The second entry will only parse the word my with default settings and will not import the word content into the database even though the import wizard implies that it will. The default settings being , delimiter and " text qualifier.

```
|my content is good|
|my|
```

Now if i change the text qualifier to NONE it parses the entire second entry and my content will be imported into the database however the first entry will wind up being in 3 different cells in the data base and will show up as

```
my|content|is|good. 
|my content
```

I used pipes to imply different cells.

This seems like a limitation in Microsoft Access. Is anyone familiar with a workaround for this?

Original content:

```
,"my,content,is,good","",

,my"content","",
```

I am using the import wizard

Comment: How are you running this import? Through code or through a wizard?

Comment: I am using the import wizard

Comment: The second line should read "my""content""", otherwise, you have non-standard csv.

Comment: So the CSV isn't formatted properly it sounds like... thanks for your help.

Comment: In other words it should read,"my""content","", or ,"my "content"", ?

Comment: For each contained quote, you should have two quotes. So `comma quote text quotequote text quotequote quote comma`. Ignore the spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a limitation of the CSV import capabilities in Access. For whatever reason, Access has always been more restrictive than Excel in its abilities to parse CSV files.

So, one workaround would be to open the CSV file in Excel, save the file as an actual Excel sheet, and then import the Excel sheet into Access. For example, the CSV file

```
this,is,a "test",CSV file,"Ugly, yes, but still parsable."
```

is "non-standard" (if one is willing to concede that there is such a thing as a CSV "standard"), and Access cannot import it directly. (It either complains of an "Unparsable Record" or it splits the last field on the commas, depending on the "Text Qualifier" setting.)

However, we can open it in Excel

[image: Excel.png]

save the file as "foo.xlsx", and then import the .xlsx file into Access

[image: Access.png]

Comment: Even though this is a nice solution, I would still be wary. For example `3,"1" long"`