# File cleaning in Golang

Tags: go

I've a csv file which looks to be corrupted, so I want to do some cleaning.

Once I'm importing the file into MS Access, I got the below, which is not as required:

[image]

I want to handle it as `txt` file for cleaning, then reading it as csv.

In the file I've some fields having `""` and some does not, and notes that those having `""` are containing a `,` inside it, examples:

Some numbers appearing as: `"2,15.0` and some appearing as `22.3` without `""`

Some texts appearing as: `Manager, Supply Chain` and some appearing as `Supervisor` without `""`

My approach for solving this, is:

1. Remove the `,` from the file if it is between `""`
2. Remove the `""` from the file

Lets say I've the lines in the file as:

```
John, supervisor, 20.22
Mark, "Manager, SC", "3,200.0"
Joseph, "Technician, Electrical", 15.2
"Selphia, Henry", "Manager, Lab", "4,250.0"
```

Then the file after cleaning should be:

```
John, supervisor, 20.22
Mark, Manager SC, 3200.0
Joseph, Technician Electrical, 15.2
Selphia Henry, Manager Lab, 4250.0
```

Any thoughts, support?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You should show sample input and desired output, as well as what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Double quotes are legal in a csv file, in fact they are a requirement for fields that contain commas or double quotes. From what you've described so far, your file does not seem to be corrupt.

Comment: @Marc sample had been added.

Comment: There is no indication that this file is corrupted. As @mkopriva mentioned, double quotes are perfectly valid in a csv file and the [encoding/csv](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) package handles them just fine. If you do want to remove all commas and double quotes, you should still parse the file as csv, process the individual fields, then write out a new csv file. But the motivation seems dubious.

Comment: section 2.5 of RFC4180 "Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files": "2.5 Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes..." https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2

Comment: @mkopriva Kinldy see my updated question including screen shoot what happen when I import it into MS Access, same happen with MS Excel.

Comment: The app that you are using to read the csv file is corrupt, not the file itself!

Comment: This is now about a broken piece of software (MS Access). Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502719/issues-with-access-parsing-double-quotes-in-a-csv-file

Comment: @Marc Kindly see my updated question including screen shoot what happen when I import it into MS Access, same happen with MS Excel.

Comment: set "text qualifier" to be double quote in that gui.

Comment: @PaulHankin Kindly see my updated question including screen shoot what happen when I import it into MS Access, same happen with MS Excel.

Comment: Thanks @PaulHankin, it is done, but let's look for it generally, how can I make the mentioned and do such cleaning in GO?

Comment: In Go, you would read the file using the `encoding/csv` package, process each field individually, then write it back to a csv file (still using the package). This works because the file is not corrupted.

Comment: The file uses `, ` (comma, space) as the field separator.   CSV uses `,` (comma) as the field separator. Whitespace is part of the field in CSV.  Fix the file by replacing `, ` with `,`, but not within a quoted field.   The suggested clean file prefixes all fields except the first with a space character. That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments provided, `set "text qualifier" to be double quote in that gui` got the issue resolved

[image]

To do proper cleaning we should not corrupt data while cleaning! `"Manager, SC"` should become `Manager, SC`.

Perform the conversion step-by-step, checking the results after each step.

```
John, supervisor, 20.22
Mark, "Manager, SC", "3,200.0"
Joseph, "Technician, Electrical", 15.2
"Selphia, Henry", "Manager, Lab", "4,250.0"
```

Read the `.csv` file as if a `.txt` file. For each line, replace commas not inside quotes `('"')` by tabs `("\t" or 0x09)`. Write the input `.csv` file, after conversion, with a `.tsv` file extension. Check the output `.tsv` file. For visibility, I have shown the tab character `("\t" or 0x09)` as `\t` in the examples.

```
John\t supervisor\t 20.22
Mark\t "Manager, SC"\t "3,200.0"
Joseph\t "Technician, Electrical"\t 15.2
"Selphia, Henry"\t "Manager, Lab"\t "4,250.0"
```

Read the `.tsv` file. For each field, trim leading and trailing spaces. If the first and last characters of the field are quotes `('"')` trim them. Write the `.tsv` file. Check the output `.tsv` file.

```
John\tsupervisor\t20.22
Mark\tManager, SC\t3,200.0
Joseph\tTechnician, Electrical\t15.2
Selphia, Henry\tManager, Lab\t4,250.0
```

Read the `.tsv` file. For each field, if removing commas and `strconv.ParseFloat` returns err == nil then remove commas. Write the `.tsv` file. Check the output `.tsv` file.

```
John\tsupervisor\t20.22
Mark\tManager, SC\t3200.0
Joseph\tTechnician, Electrical\t15.2
Selphia, Henry\tManager, Lab\t4250.0
```

Below code can do the required trimming:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

// https://yourbasic.org/golang/regexp-cheat-sheet/
func main() {
    str1 := `"Selphia, Henry", "Manager, Lab", "4,250.0"` // {}

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`"\s*|,\s*"`)

    tsv := re.ReplaceAllString(str1, "\t")
    s := strings.TrimSpace(tsv)  // to remove the leading `\t` if generated
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Regex can be checked [here](https://regex101.com/r/F1OZPh/1)

For `.tsv` files, use package encoding/csv:

```golang
rdr := csv.NewReader(file)
rdr.Comma = '\t'
```

**UPDATE**

Leading spaces in an unquoted field are significant. Using “, ” as a field separator instead of “,” is wrong. For example,

```
John, supervisor, 20.22
```

Using a comma in a numeric field (3,200.0) requires quotes to escape the comma. For example,

```
Mark, "Manager, SC", "3,200.0"
```

If we fix the last two issues then the csv file will be valid and usable. For example,

```
John, supervisor, 20.22
Mark, "Manager, SC", "3,200.0"
Joseph, "Technician, Electrical", 15.2
"Selphia, Henry", "Manager, Lab", "4,250.0"
```

becomes

```
John,supervisor,20.22
Mark,"Manager, SC",3200
Joseph,"Technician, Electrical",15.2
"Selphia, Henry","Manager, Lab",4250
```

Using Go package encoding/csv, there is a simple fix:

```golang
func cleanCSV(in io.Reader, out io.Writer) error {
    r := csv.NewReader(in)
    r.TrimLeadingSpace = true
    w := csv.NewWriter(out)
    for {
        rec, err := r.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return err
        }
        for i, fld := range rec {
            if strings.IndexByte(fld, ',') >= 0 {
                fld = strings.Replace(fld, ",", "", -1)
                if _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(fld, 64); err == nil {
                    rec[i] = fld
                }
            }
        }
        err = w.Write(rec)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    w.Flush()
    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

The program (cleancsv.go) in full: https://play.golang.org/p/tEc6eXCuBWD

```sh
$ go build cleancsv.go

$ ./cleancsv -i=clean.in.csv -o=clean.out.csv
cleaned: in: clean.in.csv out: clean.out.csv

$ cat clean.in.csv
John, supervisor, 20.22
Mark, "Manager, SC", "3,200.0"
Joseph, "Technician, Electrical", 15.2
"Selphia, Henry", "Manager, Lab", "4,250.0"

$ cat clean.out.csv
John,supervisor,20.22
Mark,"Manager, SC",3200.0
Joseph,"Technician, Electrical",15.2
"Selphia, Henry","Manager, Lab",4250.0
```

To avoid the use of quotes to escape commas in fields, the program (cleantsv.go) outputs a `tsv` file: https://play.golang.org/p/6fOTX4_FqUM

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func cleanCSV(in io.Reader, out io.Writer) error {
    r := csv.NewReader(in)
    r.TrimLeadingSpace = true
    w := bufio.NewWriter(out)
    for {
        rec, err := r.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return err
        }
        for i, fld := range rec {
            if strings.IndexByte(fld, ',') >= 0 {
                fld = strings.Replace(fld, ",", "", -1)
                if _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(fld, 64); err == nil {
                    rec[i] = fld
                }
            }
        }
        _, err = w.WriteString(strings.Join(rec, "\t"))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = w.WriteString("\n")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    err := w.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func cleanFile(inFile, outFile string) error {
    in, err := os.Open(inFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer in.Close()
    inName := in.Name()
    out, err := os.Create(outFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()
    outName := out.Name()
    err = cleanCSV(in, out)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = out.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("cleaned:", "in:", inName, "out:", outName)
    return nil
}

var (
    inFile  = flag.String("i", "", "input csv file")
    outFile = flag.String("o", "", "output tsv file")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if flag.NFlag() != 2 || *inFile == "" || *outFile == "" {
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    err := cleanFile(*inFile, *outFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Remove(*outFile)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```